# Choose multiple random integers with input

Tags: python

I've been trying to solve this problem. I would like to input a number between 1 and 5.  So for example if I choose to input number 3, I want to then randomly choose 3 numbers from a category of numbers between 1 and 10.

Comment: Keep in mind that a computer cannot generate really random numbers. It can only generate what are called _pseudo-random_ numbers. Read http://docs.python.org/library/random.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation. It depends on the application if the numbers generated by the `random` module are suitable.

Comment: Should the numbers be unique? Also, have you got any code so far?

Comment: what have you tried? If you post your attempt (however minimal), it helps others in guiding you correctly.

Comment: Im gonna try and post what I have so far.

Comment: Never mind, the answer I was looking for is at the bottom of this page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

something of this sort could work...

```
In [84]: user_input = raw_input("Enter a number between 1 to 5 :")
Enter a number between 1 to 5 :3

In [85]: selected_elem = []

In [86]: while len(selected_elem) < int(user_input):
   ....:         random_elem = random.randrange(1, 10, 1)
   ....:         if random_elem not in selected_elem:
   ....:                 selected_elem.append(random_elem)
   ....:

In [87]: print selected_elem
[1, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
random.seed()
a = 1
b = 10
randList = []
for x in range(3):
    # random integer N such that a <= N <= b
    randList.append(random.randint(a, b))
```

Or better yet:

```
import random
random.seed()
a = 1
b = 10
randList = [random.randint(a,b) for x in range(3)]
```

Comment: You probably want to `seed()` the random number generator first.

Answer (score 0):

```
myrands = [rand_int(1,10) for x in range(0,int(raw_input()))]
```

`myrands` is a list of random numbers between 1 and 10, the length is determined by user input.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach:

```
from random import choice
list_of_numbers = range(11)[1:] # the 1: drops the zero
choice(list_of_numbers) # picks a random number from the list
```

Comment: just for information ... you can also do `list_of_numbers = range(1,11)` instead of slicing the list after range

Comment: Nice! I've never used `choice` before. Good addition to the belt.